# Since r.js compiles AMD modules into one big file, where is the "asynchronous" in Asynchronous Module Definition?

Tags: javascript, require, amd, r.js

I'm finding it a little difficult to understand where the asynchronous aspect of AMD architecture exists once you have used something like r.js to bundle up all your modules into one big file.

What is the benefit (besides minification) of using r.js over simply allowing require.js to load discreet js on demand asynchronously without blocking the DOM? Surely it has to be quicker to load only what the app currently needs (vanilla require.js) than to load all that the app could ever need (compiled r.js).

Answer (score 2):

There's no single benefit of AMD if you decide to make one bundle of it, just drawbacks, as all you get is pack of code mixed with boilerplate.

If you're looking for clean solutions try CommonJS style, no boilerplate, and with right tools it's much faster than AMD (as asynchronous disk operations are faster than asynchronous network operations), with CommonJS your code becomes also environment agnostic, so you can just load your module on server (Node.js) and client, no extra configuration/hacking needed.

Check [Webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake) (I'm author of it) It's few years I develop with it. I've never looked back.

Check also some AMD -> CommonJS transition success stories: http://esa-matti.suuronen.org/blog/2013/03/22/journey-from-requirejs-to-browserify/

Answer (score 0):

I will you an example for my company. We have single page module web app (every tab in app is developed with separated team). Every team have they own code, and use some common parts.
In the module the access common parts with require, so they are sure that it will be accessible (paths are same in bundlead scripts and on server).
This gives as a possibility to make bundled files for modules, which do not have everything inside.